# Is there a one liner to convert Milliseconds to Seconds in Groovy\Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am using `${currentBuild.duration}` inside a curl command and get the build duration in milliseconds,
Is there a one liner to get it in seconds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `currentBuild.duration` member accessor will return an integer or long type in milliseconds. Therefore, you can use arithmetic operators with it to convert it to seconds:

```
currentBuild.duration / 1000
```

Since it appears from your question that you want to also implicitly cast it as a string within interpolation, then it would look something like:

```
"strings ${currentBuild.duration / 1000} strings"
```

Comment: I tested an example stage with 1.30 minutes sleep (90 seconds) but got this as the result 90623000, which is incorrect, I then used the division sign '/' which provided the correct answer. 90.37 I will mark your answer as good for pointing me into the right direction. thank you for that !